# Changing the subnet on which my beegfs cluster operates

Tags: networking, cluster, hpc, beegfs

I've added some fiber channels between the machines that constitutes my BeegFS cluster in an effort to increase throughput. However, I have to leave the old coppy ethernet in place with its addressing intact for backwards compatibility.

Is there a way I can edit the existing setup to work as it is, only over a different IP range?
Everything is set up to operate on `192.168.9.0/24` with management running on `192.168.9.101`. Do the addresses of storage-targets and management server go down into a set of files I can simply edit?

Answer (score 0):

I don't get exactly the question but first of all: BeeGFS does not support the Fiber Channel protocol nor it's a block device sharing like an FC device, it needs TCP/IP networking or RDMA (with Infiniband, RoCE or Omni-Path). BeeGFS is much more like a filer than a SAN storage.

That's stated on the product brief: https://www.beegfs.io/c/home/key-aspects-of-beegfs/

Where it reads: *BeeGFS is built on highly efficient and scalable multithreaded core components with native RDMA support. File system nodes can serve RDMA (InfiniBand, (Omni-Path), RoCE and TCP/IP) network connections at the same time and automatically switch to a redundant connection path in case any of them fails.*

There's also the same question on the BeeGFS FAQ: https://www.beegfs.io/wiki/FAQ#net_types

That's the answer regarding the Fiber Channel question. Regarding the IP change, you can aggregate multiple interfaces and consequently multiple IP addresses. To achieve this you just configure the `connNetFilterFile` and `connInterfacesFile` in each configuration file on the machine that provides the BeeGFS service, there's more info on the FAQ too: https://www.beegfs.io/wiki/FAQ#multiple_nics

Comment: It is currently operating over TCP/IP, and will remain so. It's set up with all nodes addresses on one particular subnet. I would like to alter all configurations on all machines to use a different subnet instead. When I set it all up, presumably the addresses and hostnames I entered as part of the setup went into a configuration somewhere, but I would like to alter those parameters to ensure that it communicates over a different subnet that is faster.